# React form reset

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

```
this.state = {
  name: "",
  arr: [],
  story: ""
};

add(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  story: e.target.value
});
this.state.arr.push(this.state.story);
this.form.reset();
```

}

```
 <form action="">
        <input onChange={this.b} type="text" />
        <button type="submit" className="not" onClick={this.add}>
          Next
        </button>
      </form>
      <p>You did it {this.state.name}</p>
```

**I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. I am wanting to reset state using the same function used to submit. I've tried setting state after I pushed the contents into the array but no matter what I do state remains the same. I'm a new developer so I apologize for the easy question. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in two ways.

You can get form id and reset. You need to provide id to form.

```
<form action="" id="submit-form">  // id given
        <input onChange={this.b} type="text" />
        <button type="submit" className="not" onClick={this.add}>
          Next
        </button>
      </form>
      <p>You did it {this.state.name}</p>
```

You can just use Uncontrolled ways

```
 add(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  story: e.target.value
});
this.state.arr.push(this.state.story);
  document.getElementById("submit-form").reset();}
```

or  Controlled ways.

```
     add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      story: e.target.value
    });
    this.state.arr.push(this.state.story);
     this.setState({
      story: ''   //set empty value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the boards. It really doesn't look like you're updating the **state** of your component in the code above.

I've made something in a sandbox for you to kind of have a better idea of how to update your state using essentially the same methods you're using.

Also, try to **never mutate your state**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/6jnmr50vnr